# Creating a bat file that calls an exe which calls a php file which calls a parameter

Tags: batch-file, command

well im trying to create a bat file that calls the php-cgi.exe with the file that it has to call , and the parameter that files need:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php-cgi.exe" \\\10.101.3.21\wiki\maintenance\importimages.php C:\wikimages jpg bmp
```

but i cant get it to work, it tries to open the importimages file instead of running it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check which OS you're using.  The syntax for the 'start' command has changed over time.

You used to be able to do

```
start "iexplore.exe"
```

Now, you have to supply the window title before the command you're starting:

```
start "Title Goes Here" "iexplore.exe"
```

This change was made sometime around Windows XP, so if you're using Vista, 7, or 8 keep that in mind.

I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php-cgi.exe \\\10.101.3.21\wiki\maintenance\importimages.php C:\wikimages jpg bmp"
```

Comment: it almost work, it gets the second command (the \\10.101.3.21), but now it isnt getting the third (i had to make some changes because it was searching all as a code
start "updater" "C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php-cgi.exe" \\10.101.3.21\wikitest\maintenance\importimages.php C:\wikimages jpg bmp

Comment: This is almost certainly to do with the quoting of parameters.  Try different things, but essentially you must wrap all the things that come after `start "updater"` in double quotes.  If that still doesn't work, you may want to try wrapping `php-cgi.exe`'s arguments in double quotes as well (probably escaped, such as `start "updater" "php-cgi.exe \"param1\" \"param2\" \"param3\""`.)  Not on a Windows machine so I'm afraid I can't help too much at the moment.